# How to remove audio from video android java

Tags: java, android

Can you please tell me how to remove audio from a video. I dont want to extract audio. I want to remove the audio in android application using JAVA

If it is possible can you please tell the framework or any library from which I can do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those who are marking negative to this question, It will be great if you explain me why you're marking negative? Its better if you provide me the answer and I will be thankful.

Comment: People like to see what you have tried or looked for already to support your question. Maybe that's why they're voting down.

Comment: I asked this question Bcoz in iOS (both swift and objective c) it is possible.

Comment: check dis one https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html

Comment: I already searched about this. But everytime I found links in which they answered or show the extraction of audio from video using java

Comment: Thanks @V-V, I got the Solution maybe this will help. I need to extract the videotrack from the movie and write it to buffer and I can make new movie file.

Comment: didi you get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite misleading still i guess you want to remove audio from video, for that you need to use ffmpeg framework and you can remove audio https://superuser.com/a/268986 as suggested in this post.

Comment: in android, using java.

Comment: No you can not do that using java you need to follow process as needed for ffmpeg usage.

Comment: I asked this question Bcoz in iOS (both swift and objective c) it is possible.